# Method call with null date

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying Junit test calls with null date.

Simplified code:

```
@Test
public void testWithoutDate () {
    WeatherForecast weatherForecast = new WeatherForecast();
    String forecast = weatherForecast.getCityWeather("Madrid", null);
    assertTrue(forecast, true);
}

// Class to test

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import org.json.JSONArray;

public class WeatherForecast {

    public String getCityWeather(String city, Date datetime) throws IOException {

        if (datetime == null) {
            datetime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        }

        HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new NetHttpTransport().createRequestFactory();
        HttpRequest request = requestFactory
            .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl("https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=" + city));
        String rawResponse = request.execute().parseAsString();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(rawResponse);
        return jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).get("woeid").toString();
    }
}
```

}

I want to call the method dummy with an empty date and if so set that date to today but as expected when I call it from Junit NullPointerException comes to play.

Is there any workaround?

P.S: Sorry for my really bad English skills.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. It's not obvious why this code would throw a NPE.

Comment: Works for me:

`@Test
    public void testWithoutDate() {
        String city = "Texas";
        dummy(city, null);
    }

    public void dummy(String city, Date date) {
        if (date == null) {
            date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        }
        System.out.println("All good");
    }`

Comment: There is no variable "date", should be "datetime": `if (datetime == null)` ?

Answer (score 1):

This work for me :

WeatherForecast.class

```
public class WeatherForecast {
  public String getCityWeather(String city, Date date) throws IOException, JSONException 
    {

        if (date == null) {
            date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        }

        HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new NetHttpTransport().createRequestFactory();
        HttpRequest request = requestFactory
                .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl("https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=" + city));
        String rawResponse = request.execute().parseAsString();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(rawResponse);
        return jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).get("woeid").toString();
    }}
```

Testcase :

```
 @Test
public void testWithoutDate () throws IOException, JSONException {
    WeatherForecast weatherForecast = new WeatherForecast();
    String forecast = weatherForecast.getCityWeather("Madrid", null);
    assertTrue(forecast, true);
}
```